# Can I make a payable function with zero ether value?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethers.js, dapp-development, payable

I have a payable function in solidity with the price to pay that can be dynamic, in particular, sometimes it can be 0. I can correctly call the payable function when the price is higher than zero, but when it is zero ethers.js throws an error. Am I doing something wrong on the front end or is it theoretically wrong having a payable function with a zero ether value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is totally fine to not send any Ethers to a `payable` function. In fact, adding that keyword (even if the logic doesn't utilize any Ethers) saves you a bit in gas since the EVM then doesn't need to check internally whether the transaction's `value` is zero. But that's rather senseless optimization in my opinion.

So if you get errors, it should be related to something else.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it was a frontend error. Thanks.

Comment: Wow! Didn't know it saved gas.